# customize button in a kendo grid edit popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

need help about customizing buttons both in a kendo grid edit popup, and the edit button.

if I customize the edit button of the command

```
columns = [
        { field: "desc_iva", title: "Descrizione", width: 45 },
        { field: "codice_iva", title: "Codice", width: 45 },
        { field: "imposta", title: "imposta", width: 45 },
        { field: "indetr", title: "Indetr", width: 45 },
        { field: "note", title: "Note", width: 45 },
        { field: "predefinito", title: "Pred.", width: 45 },
        {
            command: [{
                name: "destroy",
                text: "Elimina"
            },                
            {
                name: "edit",                   
                text: "Customited text"
            }
            ]
        }
];
```

I can't change the buttons text into the edit popup, and if i customize the "Change" and "Update" buttons in the popup...

```
columns = [
        { field: "desc_iva", title: "Descrizione", width: 45 },
        { field: "codice_iva", title: "Codice", width: 45 },
        { field: "imposta", title: "imposta", width: 45 },
        { field: "indetr", title: "Indetr", width: 45 },
        { field: "note", title: "Note", width: 45 },
        { field: "predefinito", title: "Pred.", width: 45 },
        {
            command: [{
                name: "destroy",
                text: "Elimina"
            },                
            {
                name: "edit",                   
                text: {
                    title: "adsfg",
                    update: "Aggiorna",
                    cancel: "Cancella"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
];
```

can't change the edit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command: [{
            name: "destroy",
            text: "Elimina"
        },                
        {
            name: "edit",                   
            text: {
                edit: "Modifica",
                update: "Aggiorna",
                cancel: "Cancella"
            }
        }
        ]
```

This is the solution!!!